# error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds - solution included, clarification needed

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define NUM_ROWS 5
#define NUM_COLS 10

void dynamic_allocation_malloc3();

int main() { 
   dynamic_allocation_malloc3();
}

void dynamic_allocation_malloc3() {

    int (**ptr)[]; //ptr is a pointer to a pointer to a 1-d integer array
    ptr = malloc(NUM_ROWS * sizeof(int(*)[])); // allocate as many as NUM_ROWS pointers to 1-d int arrays. The memory holds pointers to rows 

    for(int row=0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++) {

       ptr[row] = malloc(NUM_COLS * sizeof(int)); 

       for(int col=0; col < NUM_COLS; col++) {
            ptr[row][col] = 17;
      }
    }
}
```

This code gives the following error on compile:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 dynamic_allocation_scratch.c 
dynamic_allocation_scratch.c: In function ‘dynamic_allocation_malloc3’:
dynamic_allocation_scratch.c:23:13: error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds
             ptr[row][col] = 17;
             ^
dynamic_allocation_scratch.c:23:13: error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds
```

The fix is to replace

```
ptr[row][col] = 17;
```

with

```
(*ptr[row])[col] = 17; //de-reference the pointer to 1-d array to get the array and then use col index
```

Question:

I want to clarify my understanding here. Did I correctly reason why the fix is working?
Any further clarifications into why the original code was not working will also be appreciated.

Comment: ```int (**ptr)[]; //ptr is a pointer to a pointer to a 1-d integer array```
This is not a 2D array, it's 3D.

Comment: `int (**ptr)[];` is a *Pointer-to-pointer-to-Array-of-unspecified-size* (funny how the error matches the problem). `int **ptr` will do..... It seems like you have a misunderstanding. `int **ptr` is a single pointer-to-pointer. You allocate `NUM_ROWS` pointers in one block, and then allocate a block of `NUM_COLS * sizeof(int)` and assign the start of each block to your allocated pointers.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Note that, the fix in my solution will work, without specifying the array dimensions. Did you happen to notice the fix I proposed in my question ? Any comments on that ?

Comment: Yes, but removing the unspecified level of indirection by dereferencing the pointer doesn't solve the original unspecified size problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide how many levels of indirection you want. A pointer to a pointer to an array makes three levels, but

```
ptr[row][col]
```

is only two levels. Let's see

```
ptr    // a pointer to a pointer to an array
ptr[row]     // a pointer to an array
ptr[row][col] // an array
ptr[row][col] = 17 // an array equals 17; explain that to your nearest rubber duck
```

Comment: `ptr[row][col]` is a semantic error as `[col]` cannot be applied to *pointer to array of unknown bound*

Answer (score 1):

`ptr[row]` has type *pointer to array of `int` of unknown bound*.  So `ptr[row][col]` would mean "the `col`-th array of `int` of unknown bound", which cannot be computed since we do not know the size of each array in order to find the next array in memory.

The first one, `*(ptr[row])`, is valid since this does not involve any arithmetic. That expression has type *array of `int` of unknown bound*, and you can use the operator `[col]` on such an array .